# Pink spots on African Drawf Frog

Tags: frogs

My sons pet  African dwarf frog  Developed these weird pink spots. Is it bacteria or  parasite ?[image]

Comment: what is the temparature and moisture level in the tank?

Comment: if under the front arms, they are a normal gland that all male ADF have